# What is the purpose of the file "computed_hashes.json" in a google chrome extension?

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In some google chrome extensions, there is a `computed_hashes.json` file. I didn't found any documentation about this file. So it will be kind if i can get some explanations.

Below is an extract from this file:

```
{
    "file_hashes": [{
            "block_hashes": ["THf/ne1nArt1trn0Uf4jA/7WR+rNdgXBOuEkU0Y44YU="],
            "block_size": 4096,
            "path": "_locales/en_US/messages-sim.json"
        }, {
            "block_hashes": ["LZqMS69G7bOe059IFEKxhxMlxa4aFimV2SdQWmB7CF8="],
            "block_size": 4096,
            "path": "adguard/adguard-api.js"
        },
...
}
```

What does `block_hashes` represent?

Comment: It is to ensure the integrity of the files, to make sure they were not modified.

Comment: ok :) thank you for the response... @IvánNokonoko...  do you know what is the hashing algorithm to use? is there a specific one?

Comment: I don't know the algorithm, sorry.

Comment: As I explore in my answer below, the hash algorithm is SHA256: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72891514/1137085

Answer (score 4):

## Short Answer

`computed_hashes.json` calculates a hash of the blocks of the files included in the extension, which is presumably used for file integrity and/or security purposes to ensure the files haven't been corrupted/tampered with.

Looking at the `ComputedHashes::GetHashesForContent` function in the `extensions/browser/computed_hashes.cc` file of the chromium source, the `block_hashes` are [computed using the SHA256 hashing algorithm (`crypto::SecureHash::Create(crypto::SecureHash::SHA256))`)](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.cc;l=305-313)

If you want to know more about the `verified_contents.json` file which is often used alongside/in tandem with `computed_hashes.json`, you can read more about it (and my associated deep dive) [in my other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72892156/1137085).

## Deep Dive Explanation

To determine the hashing algorithm used, and how it is calculated, we can search the chromium source code for `computed_hashes` as follows:

- https://source.chromium.org/search?q=computed_hashes

This returns a number of interesting files, including:

- [`extensions/browser/computed_hashes.h`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.h?q=computed_hashes)
- [`extensions/browser/computed_hashes.cc`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.cc?q=computed_hashes)

[Looking in `computed_hashes.h`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.h;l=27-28?q=computed_hashes) we can see a comment that suggests it uses the SHA256 hashing algorithm, computed over the blocks of the files inside the extension:

```cc
// A class for storage and serialization of a set of SHA256 block hashes
// computed over the files inside an extension.
```

[We can also see](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.h;l=115-126?q=computed_hashes) a few function prototypes that sound like they are used for computing the hashes:

```cc
  // Computes hashes for files in |extension_root|. Returns nullopt upon any
  // failure. Callback |should_compute_hashes_for| is used to determine whether
  // we need hashes for a resource or not.
  // TODO(https://crbug.com/796395#c24) To support per-file block size instead
  // of passing |block_size| as an argument make callback
  // |should_compute_hashes_for| return optional<int>: nullopt if hashes are not
  // needed for this file, block size for this file otherwise.
  static absl::optional<ComputedHashes::Data> Compute(
      const base::FilePath& extension_root,
      int block_size,
      const IsCancelledCallback& is_cancelled,
      const ShouldComputeHashesCallback& should_compute_hashes_for_resource);
```

```cc
  // Builds hashes for one resource and checks them against
  // verified_contents.json if needed. Returns nullopt if nothing should be
  // added to computed_hashes.json for this resource.
  static absl::optional<std::vector<std::string>> ComputeAndCheckResourceHash(
      const base::FilePath& full_path,
      int block_size);
```

```cc
  // Returns the SHA256 hash of each |block_size| chunk in |contents|.
  static std::vector<std::string> GetHashesForContent(
      const std::string& contents,
      size_t block_size);
```

We can find the function definitions for these in `computed_hashes.cc`:

- [`ComputedHashes::Compute`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.cc;l=195-234?q=computed_hashes) calls [`base::FileEnumerator`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/files/file_enumerator.h;l=117-152) to recursively discover all files in the `extension_root`, adds them to a  [`SortedFilePathSet`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.cc;l=38) (`std::set<base::FilePath>`), loops over the paths in sorted order, checks `should_compute_hashes_for_resource.Run` to see if the file should have it's hash calculated, then calls [`ComputeAndCheckResourceHash`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.cc;l=326-340?q=computed_hashes) to calculate the hash
- [`ComputedHashes::ComputeAndCheckResourceHash`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.cc;l=326-340?q=computed_hashes) calls [`base::ReadFileToString`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/files/file_util.cc;l=296-312) (which then calls `ReadFileToStringWithMaxSize` that reads the file as a binary file with mode `rb`) to load the contents of the file, and then passes this to [`GetHashesForContent`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.cc;l=294-323?q=computed_hashes) to calculate the hashes over the file content.

```cc
std::vector<std::string> ComputedHashes::GetHashesForContent(
    const std::string& contents,
    size_t block_size) {
  size_t offset = 0;
  std::vector<std::string> hashes;
  // Even when the contents is empty, we want to output at least one hash
  // block (the hash of the empty string).
  do {
    const char* block_start = contents.data() + offset;
    DCHECK(offset <= contents.size());
    size_t bytes_to_read = std::min(contents.size() - offset, block_size);
    std::unique_ptr<crypto::SecureHash> hash(
        crypto::SecureHash::Create(crypto::SecureHash::SHA256));
    hash->Update(block_start, bytes_to_read);

    std::string buffer;
    buffer.resize(crypto::kSHA256Length);
    hash->Finish(std::data(buffer), buffer.size());
    hashes.push_back(std::move(buffer));

    // If |contents| is empty, then we want to just exit here.
    if (bytes_to_read == 0)
      break;

    offset += bytes_to_read;
  } while (offset < contents.size());

  return hashes;
}
```

Here we can see that it uses `crypto::SecureHash::Create(crypto::SecureHash::SHA256)` over to calculate the block hashes.

Comment: note: verified_contents.json only contains checksums, but no signatures. in the crx file, only the compressed data is signed, so the uncompressed data cannot be verified, unless you [reproduce the zip archive with the original compression parameters](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReverseEngineering/comments/1ahd36y/reverse_engineer_the_exact_lowlevel_compression/)...

Answer (score 1):

As Iván Nokonoko said, it's a hash value likely used for file integrity checking.  The hash is base64 encoded and decodes to 20 bytes.  This is most likely a SHA-1 hash value.

Comment: As I explore in my answer below, the hash algorithm is actually SHA256 rather than SHA1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72891514/1137085