# What is the purpose of the computed_hashes.json and verified_contents.json files in a secure Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've seen some Chrome extensions that hashes their folder and file names. They have a folder named '*metadata*' and two files inside it: 'computed_hashes.json' and 'verified_contents.json'. What are these files, what do they do and how can I get them or use them?

Comment: Chrome creates those automatically, not extensions.

Comment: So my Chrome extension will hash the file and folder names automatically?

Comment: No, your extension won't do anything. Chrome does that.

Comment: @wOxxOm Do you know the hashing algorithm of `computed_hashes.json` ?

Comment: No, but it should be somewhere in the [source code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src).

Comment: Looking at https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.h;l=27-28?q=computed_hashes&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc it sounds like the hashes are probably SHA256 block hashes

Answer (score 4):

## `computed_hashes.json`

`computed_hashes.json` calculates the SHA256 hash of the blocks of the files included in the extension, which is presumably used for file integrity and/or security purposes to ensure the files haven't been corrupted/tampered with.

I go into this in depth in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72891514/1137085), where I reference the various relevant sections in the Chromium source code.

The main relevant files are:

- [`extensions/browser/computed_hashes.h`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.h?q=computed_hashes)
- [`extensions/browser/computed_hashes.cc`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.cc?q=computed_hashes)

And within this, the main relevant functions are:

- [`Compute`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.cc;l=195-234?q=computed_hashes)
- [`ComputeAndCheckResourceHash`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.cc;l=326-340?q=computed_hashes)
- [`GetHashesForContent`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.cc;l=294-323?q=computed_hashes)

And the actual hash calculation can be seen in the [`ComputedHashes::GetHashesForContent`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.cc;l=294-323?q=computed_hashes) function.

## `verified_contents.json`

### Short Answer

This is used for file integrity and/or security purposes to ensure that the extension files haven't been corrupted/tampered with.

`verified_contents.json` ensures that the Base64 encoded `payload` of the `signed_content` object within the object with a `description` of `treehash per file` validates against the `signature` of the object within `signatures` that has a `header.kid` of `webstore`. This is validated using `crypto::SignatureVerifier::RSA_PKCS1_SHA256` across the concatenated values of `protected` + `.` + `payload`.

If the signature validates correctly, the SHA256 hash of the blocks of the files included in the extension are then calculated and compared as per `computed_hashes.json` (described above).

### Deep Dive Explanation

To determine the internal specifics of how `verified_contents.json` is created/validated, we can search the chromium source code for `verified_contents` as follows:

- https://source.chromium.org/search?q=verified_contents

This returns a number of interesting files, including:

- [`extensions/browser/verified_contents.h`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/verified_contents.h?q=verified_contents)
- [`extensions/browser/verified_contents.cc`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/verified_contents.cc?q=verified_contents)

Looking in `verified_contents.h` we can see a comment describing the purpose of `verified_contents.json`, and how it's created by the webstore:

```cc
// This class encapsulates the data in a "verified_contents.json" file
// generated by the webstore for a .crx file. That data includes a set of
// signed expected hashes of file content which can be used to check for
// corruption of extension files on local disk.
```

We can also see a number of function prototypes that sound like they are used for parsing and validating the `verified_contents.json` file:

```cc
  // Returns verified contents after successfully parsing verified_contents.json
  // file at |path| and validating the enclosed signature. Returns nullptr on
  // failure.
  // Note: |public_key| must remain valid for the lifetime of the returned
  // object.
  static std::unique_ptr<VerifiedContents> CreateFromFile(
      base::span<const uint8_t> public_key,
      const base::FilePath& path);
```

```
  // Returns verified contents after successfully parsing |contents| and
  // validating the enclosed signature. Returns nullptr on failure. Note:
  // |public_key| must remain valid for the lifetime of the returned object.
  static std::unique_ptr<VerifiedContents> Create(
      base::span<const uint8_t> public_key,
      base::StringPiece contents);
```

```
  // Returns the base64url-decoded "payload" field from the |contents|, if
  // the signature was valid.
  bool GetPayload(base::StringPiece contents, std::string* payload);
```

```
  // The |protected_value| and |payload| arguments should be base64url encoded
  // strings, and |signature_bytes| should be a byte array. See comments in the
  // .cc file on GetPayload for where these come from in the overall input
  // file.
  bool VerifySignature(const std::string& protected_value,
                       const std::string& payload,
                       const std::string& signature_bytes);
```

We can find the function definitions for these in `verified_contents.cc`:

- [`VerifiedContents::CreateFromFile`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/verified_contents.cc;l=82-109?q=verified_contents) calls [`base::ReadFileToString`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/files/file_util.cc;l=296-312) (which then calls `ReadFileToStringWithMaxSize` that reads the file as a binary file with mode `rb`) to load the contents of the file, and then passes this to [`Create`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/verified_contents.cc;l=111-197?q=verified_contents)
- [`VerifiedContents::Create`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/verified_contents.cc;l=111-197?q=verified_contents)

  - calls [`VerifiedContents::GetPayload`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/verified_contents.cc;l=213-316) to extract/validate/decode the contents of the Base64 encoded `payload` field within `verified_contents.json` (see below for deeper explanation of this)
  - parses this as JSON with [`base::JSONReader::Read`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/json/json_reader.cc;l=66-79)
  - extracts the `item_id` key, validates it with [`crx_file::id_util::IdIsValid`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:components/crx_file/id_util.cc;l=90-102), and adds it to `verified_contents` as `extension_id_`
  - extracts the `item_version` key, validates it with [`Version::IsValid()`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/version.cc), and adds it to `verified_contents` as `version_`
  - extracts all of the `content_hashes` objects and

    - verifies that the `format` of each is `treehash`
    - extracts the `block_size` and `hash_block_size`, ensures they have the same value, and adds`block_size` to `verified_contents` as `block_size_`
    - extracts all of the `files` objects

      - extracts the `path` and `root_hash` keys and ensures that `root_hash` is Base64 decodeable
    - calculates the `canonical_path` using [`content_verifier_utils::CanonicalizeRelativePath`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/content_verifier/content_verifier_utils.cc;l=25-34) and [`base::FilePath::FromUTF8Unsafe`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/files/file_path.cc;l=653-656), and inserts it into `root_hashes_` in the `verified_contents`
  - finally, returns the `verified_contents`
- [`VerifiedContents::GetPayload`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/json/json_reader.cc;l=66-79)

  - parses the `contents` as JSON with [`base::JSONReader::Read`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:components/crx_file/id_util.cc;l=90-102)
  - finds an object in the JSON that has the `description` key set to `treehash per file`

    - extracts the `signed_content` object

      - extracts the `signatures` array

        - finds an object in the `signatures` array that has a `header.kid` set to `webstore`

          - extracts the `protected` / `signature` keys and Base64 decodes the `signature` into `signature_bytes`
      - extracts the `payload` key
      - calls [`VerifySignature`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/verified_contents.cc;l=318-342) with `protected` / `payload` / `signature_bytes`

        - if the signature is valid, Base64 decodes the `payload` into a JSON string
- [`VerifiedContents::VerifySignature`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/verified_contents.cc;l=318-342)

  - calls [`SignatureVerifier::VerifyInit`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:crypto/signature_verifier.cc;l=26-81) using `crypto::SignatureVerifier::RSA_PKCS1_SHA256`
  - uses this to validate `protected_value` + `.` + `payload`

Since this didn't show how the file hashes themselves were verified, I then searched for where `VerifiedContents::CreateFromFile` was called:

- https://source.chromium.org/search?q=VerifiedContents::CreateFromFile

Which pointed me to the following files:

- [`extensions/browser/content_verifier/content_hash.cc`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/content_verifier/content_hash.cc?q=VerifiedContents::CreateFromFile)

Where

- `VerifiedContents::CreateFromFile` is called by [`ReadVerifiedContents`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/content_verifier/content_hash.cc;l=46-62?q=VerifiedContents::CreateFromFile)
- `ReadVerifiedContents` is called by [`ContentHash::GetVerifiedContents`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/content_verifier/content_hash.cc;l=169-192?q=VerifiedContents::CreateFromFile), and when the contents are successfully verified, it will pass them to `verified_contents_callback`
- `GetVerifiedContents` is called by [`ContentHash::Create`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/content_verifier/content_hash.cc;l=89-110?q=VerifiedContents::CreateFromFile), which passes [`ContentHash::GetComputedHashes`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/content_verifier/content_hash.cc;l=264-288) as the `verified_contents_callback`
- `ContentHash::GetComputedHashes` calls [`ContentHash::BuildComputedHashes`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/content_verifier/content_hash.cc;l=391-457)
- `ContentHash::BuildComputedHashes` will read/create the `computed_hashes.json` file by calling [`file_util::GetComputedHashesPath`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/common/file_util.cc;l=553-555), `ComputedHashes::CreateFromFile`, [`CreateHashes`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/content_verifier/content_hash.cc;l=354-389) (which calls [`ComputedHashes::Compute`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/computed_hashes.cc;l=195-234)), etc

Note that `ComputedHashes::CreateFromFile` and `ComputedHashes::Compute` are the functions described in the `computed_hashes.json` section above (used to calculate the SHA256 hash of the blocks of the files included in the extension), and which I go into much more detail about in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72891514/1137085).